# add values in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to add 2 inputted values in a for loop and then print them off.
This seems really obvious but I just cannot seem to figure it out
If I input 2 for price and 2 for quantity for the first loop and then the same for the second loop the value I get when I print is 6 rather than 8 (2*2)+(2*2)

```
items = []
purchased_i = []
price = 0
shop = input("Enter the shop you are visiting: ")
count = int(input("How many items do you want to add?"))

for i in range(count):

  choice = input("Enter your item: ")
  quantity = int(input("How many do you need?: "))
  purchased = input("Have you purchased this item(s)?: ")

  if purchased.lower() == "yes": 
    purchased_i.append(purchased)

  elif purchased.lower() == "no":
    items.append(choice)
    choice2 = input("Would you like to purchase this item(s)?: ")
    if choice2.lower() == "yes":
      price = int(input("How much would you be willing to pay per item(s)?: £"))
    print("The priority for this item is", len(items))

  price += price * quantity

print("Your total price is £",price)
```

Comment: You seem to be using the variable `price` for both the total cost and the per-item cost. At the end of the first loop, `price` is `4`. During the second loop, you reset it to `2` at `price = int(input("How much ..."))`. When you reach `price += price * quantity`, price is still `2`, so that's computing `2 + (2*2)`. Note that the total from the previous loop is lost.

Comment: For small programs like this one, build a [mre] for the purpose of debugging (e.g. hardcoding `count` and only asking for `price` and `quantity`). It's helpful to print the state of the program during the loops (for example number of loop, and values of relevant variables before and after critical calculations). [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code by adding the total price for each item into the total_price variable. Your previous code does not adds the price back to the total_price variable each time the customer entered the price and quantity. See below the code for details:

```
items = []
purchased_i = []
total_price = 0  # initialize the price to zero

shop = input("Enter the shop you are visiting: ")
count = int(input("How many items do you want to add?"))

for i in range(count):
    choice = input("Enter your item: ")
    quantity = int(input("How many do you need?: "))
    if_purchased = input("Have you purchased this item(s)?: ")

    if if_purchased.lower() == "yes": # if the customer entered yes for if_purchased:
        price = int(input(f"How much did you pay for this item?: £"))
        total_price += price * quantity  # add  the total price 
        purchased_i.append(if_purchased)

    elif if_purchased.lower() == "no": #if the customer entered no for if_purchased:
        items.append(choice)
        choice2 = input("Would you like to purchase this item(s)?: ")
        if choice2.lower() == "yes":
            price = int(input(f"How much would you be willing to pay for this item?: £"))
            total_price += price * quantity  # Accumulate the total price
            print("The priority for this item is", len(items))

print("Your total price is £", total_price)
```

You can check the sample output here:

```
> Enter the shop you are visiting: CVS 
> How many items do you want to add?3
> Enter your item: candy 
> How many do you need?: 2
> Have you purchased this item(s)?: yes
> How much did you pay for this item?: £2
> Enter your item: apple 
> How many do you need?: 3
> Have you purchased this item(s)?: no
> Would you like to purchase this item(s)?: yes
> How much would you be willing to pay for this item?: £3
> The priority for this item is 1
> Enter your item: bread
> How many do you need?: 1
> Have you purchased this item(s)?: yes
> How much did you pay for this item?:£1
> Your total price is £ 14
```

Therefore my total price for candy, apple, and bread would be:

> 2 candies * 2 + 3 apples * 3 + 1 bread * 1 = 4 + 9 + 1 = 14

Please let me know if this helps!

Answer (score -2):

If you are doing price = 2 and quantity = 2, then:

```
price += 2*2 
Output: 6
```

If you are trying to get 8 then use this:

```
price *= price * quantity
Output: 8
```

If that didn't make sense I can try rewriting it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I really don't think this is what the OP actually wants to do. It makes a lot of sense to calculate a total price as price_per_item by number_of_items and then **add** it to the previous total.

Comment: Thanks! It's how I interpreted it, but I can see where you come from :)